# How to connect VBScript (Excel) to SQL Server web database (via IP)?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, database-connection

We're trying to connect an Excel document with a VBScript macro to a database stored in web server but for some reason doesn't recognizes the user and throws an error repeatedly.

I discarded a connection issue since it returns an SQL error instead of something like a timeout or server doesn't exists or something like that.

We're trying to connect to the server using the ip address.
We checked that the logging method is on mixed (win and sql) and remote connections to the server are enabled.
If I use the credentials provided in the connection string (username and password) I can log in to SQL Server without any issue.
We tried a direct connection (external vpn) because we thought it could be our firewall, but got the same error.

The error I get (not the original since it's in Spanish but is very similar to this):
[image]

The code trying the connection (test data but similar to reality).

```vb
Sub excel_sqlsrv()
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConn = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=10.20.30.5;Database=mydb;UID=sa;PWD=abcd12345;"
conn.Open strConn
strSqL = "SELECT * FROM USERS"
rs.Open strSqL
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ODBC Data Source Administrator to create a connection named mydb and test it works. Then use

```vb
Sub excel_sqlsrv()

    Const strConn = "mydb" ' ODBC source
    Const strsql = "SELECT * FROM USERS"
    
    Dim conn As Object, rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    conn.Open strConn
    
    If conn.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        Dim i, s
        For i = 0 To conn.Errors.Count - 1
            s = s & conn.Errors(i) & vbLf
        Next
        MsgBox s
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set rs = conn.Execute(strsql)
        Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End If
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: HI! Thanks for your answer, i need to connect to a server with a ip address, where should i put it? where it says odbc source? thanks for your help so far

Comment: @black-soul You enter the IP and credentials in the administrator screen. I've added screenshot of the location, it's under Windows Administrative Tools.

Comment: i tried what you suggested me, i entered it as DSN user and tried with ODBC drivers as well as with SQL Server natives, what i noticed is that it detects the IP where the server is, what is failing at now is recognizing the user and password as i said above when i log in with those credentials it works fine. thanks for your suggestion!!

Comment: @black-soul How are you logging in successfully, is it using SQL Server Management Studio ? I have update my answer to show error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using OLEDB provider instead of ADODB.

Comment: i just change the driver to OLEDB? i'm kinda forgot how to do that haha

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SQL Server instance instead of just the plain IP address as a parameter.

For example:

```
Const strConn = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" & _
                    "SERVER=SQL-INSTANCE\INSTANCENAME; DATABASE=DATABASENAME; UID=USER; PWD=PASSWORD;"
```

I had a similar if not the same issue and this solved it.

Add the ODBC origin the data source with the correct login credentials.
When you add the ODBC data origins don't add it as DSN User but as DSN System instead.

Comment: gonna give it a try, won't waste anything