# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Excel VBA is throwing this error:

> Multiple-step OLE DB Operation generated errors

on the line : `conn.Open strConn`

I'm trying to get an integer data from a table in SQL Server database. How do I resolve it?

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim sql As String
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim age As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    strConn = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL; rest of my connection string"
    sql = "SELECT Age FROM [dbo].[SimpleTable] WHERE ID = 2"
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    conn.Open strConn
    
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    rs.Open sql, conn
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    age = rs.Fields("Age").Value
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "The age for ID=2 is: " & age

    conn.Close
    
End Sub
```

I tried different solutions provided online but is not working. I wrote some Python code with the connection string and it is a success, which indicate that is not the problem of the connection.

Comment: If the error is on `conn.Open strConn` then it could be your connection string.

Comment: Can you create a working connection using  the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75073153/how-to-connect-vbscript-excel-to-sql-server-web-database-via-ip/75075219#75075219)

Comment: But I tested my connection string with python and it is working properly.

Comment: Did you test your connection string in Python using `pyodbc`... or `pyado`? The keywords ODBC and OLE DB connection strings aren't always compatible.

Comment: I tested using pyodbc. In my Excel VBA, I used the connection string acquired in Visual Studio with right click on it to show the property. Is there any modification I need to do to it?

Comment: How can we know?

Comment: Data Source=OMNI-GRACE;Initial Catalog=simpledb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False
This is the connection string that I got.

Comment: We need to see the connection string you have as it is on the code, the way you have it. Quotations matter, commas matter,  some properties in the string may need them, etcetera. Update your question with the code you have.

Comment: The connection string that I posted above is the one that I put into the code.

Comment: What is the column type for Age in the database?  Perhaps a type conversion in the query if it's something weird like TEXT.  Perhaps a bit of error handling to identify where the error occurs.

Comment: Also, is VBA integer 16-bit or 32-bit?  Converted to 32-bit?  Perhaps a Long instead?

Comment: Try `strConn ="DSN=OMNI-GRACE"`